# Foreach & While Producing Duplicate Output

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, while-loop

I'm still working to pick up PHP and I've spent a good deal of time on this code, and am almost to where I need to be. Basically, the code is intended to grab WP posts from the past 10 days, pick two at random, then display the first image in the post and link to said post. It is also supposed to set the first image with the class .second and the second with the class .third. Unfortunately, it's working to some degree, but keeps producing duplicate copies of the same image. The array seems to be working, except I just need one less copy of each image. Here's the code, minus the date filter and the catch_that_image() function, both of which are working fine:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$banner_class = array('second','third');
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '2' ));

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
if (!empty($the_query)) {
foreach ($banner_class as $value){ ?>
<div class="banner small image <?php echo $value; ?>" >
<?php echo '<a href="'. get_permalink().'">'; ?>
<img src="<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>" width="300px"> 
<?php echo '</a></div>';
}
}

endwhile;


remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

I'm sure it's an easy solution and undoubtedly has something to do with the while and foreach being used together. Here's the output: http://www.mymusicisbetterthanyours.com/slider-test/

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$n = 0;
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
    <div class="banner small image <?php echo $banner_class[$n]; ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>" width="300px"></a>
    </div> 
<?php $n ++; endwhile; ?>
```

get rid of that foreach loop in the actual loop. You're writing the html twice in each iteration that way. Add a basic counter for the banner class. In this case $n, then increment that in each iteration of the post loop instead.

By the way, I simplified your output. You don't need to check if the query is empty. That's what that while condition is doing. And breaking in and out of php to write sections of html doesnt make sense. I also see nothing in your query that guarantees the random posts are restricted to the last 10 days.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Really appreciate the prompt response! The filter for the posts was elsewhere (functions.php) but that is working just fine, so I figured I didn't need to include it. I still clearly have a lot to learn but this helps a great deal!